H2 get date in wrong time zone when calling method from different packages
I save a record with date in h2 DB. Server time is UTC+3. When saving, it is converted to UTC, i.e. it becomes three hours less. But when trying to read a record from DB, time decreases by another three hours! How to avoid this?
The problem appeared after updating com.h2database.h2 library from version 2.1.212 to 2.2.220 (spring was also updated to 6, java to 17 and many other libs).
Test file:
package myProject;

@SpringBootTest
public class serviceTest {
    @Test
    public void testCreateRefreshToken() {
        var token = refreshTokenService.createRefreshToken();
        var allTokens1 = refreshTokenService.findAll();
        assertEquals(token.getExpiryDate(), allTokens1.get(0).getExpiryDate());
    }
}

Service:
package myProject.service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RefreshTokenService {
    @Transactional
    public RefreshToken createRefreshToken() {
        RefreshToken refreshToken = new RefreshToken();
        refreshToken.setExpiryDate(Instant.now());
        refreshToken.setToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        refreshToken = refreshTokenRepository.save(refreshToken);

        var allTokens = findAll();
        return allTokens.get(0);
    }
}

DAO:
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RefreshToken {

    @NonNull
    private String token;

    @NonNull
    private Instant expiryDate;
}

I run test in 18:00. Result:
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :2024-08-26T15:00:32.736839533Z
Actual   :2024-08-26T12:00:32.736840Z


Please also add your connection property to h2 database.

Explain exactly what you mean by "when trying to read a record from DB".

Exactly what is the data type of your column?

Use LocalDateTime instead of Instant

How are you retrieving?

when trying to read a record from DB

You really should have explained what you mean there. Did you use a database access tool to query the database? Did you write Java code using JDBC? Did you use Spring to retrieve an object?
Latest version

version 2.1.212 to 2.2.220

Why would you bother to update from one outdated version to another outdated version? Current version is 2.3.232.
You can easily find the current version on the Cheat Sheet page. Or use any Maven repository to see a list of releases.
Instant not in JDBC

private Instant expiryDate;

Instant is not supported by JDBC.
I highly recommend reading the JDBC specification so you can understand the tools you’ve chosen to use. JDBC version 4.3 has been current since 2017-04-17.
A value from a column of a type akin to the SQL Standard type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, such as H2’s TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE type, in JDBC 4.2 and higher maps to the Java class OffsetDateTime.
Perhaps Spring or Hibernate will retrieve an OffsetDateTime object and convert to Instant. I do not know; I do not use Spring or Hibernate.
H2 is not the problem
As for your premise of "H2 get date in wrong time zone", I doubt we have a problem with H2 here. H2 does store an OffsetDateTime with its offset intact. That same offset is retrieved.
Your problem is part of the complexity of overlaying frameworks on top of JDBC: Deciphering what is database behavior versus what is framework behavior becomes problematic.
Example app
Let's get Spring and Hibernate out of the way. Here is a demo app to show you H2’s actual behavior, in straight JDBC. We insert 2024-08-27T00:36:16.317504+03:00 into the database. And we retrieve 2024-08-27T00:36:16.317504+03:00.
package work.basil.example.db;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class ExH2SaveMoment
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        ExH2SaveMoment app = new ExH2SaveMoment( );
        app.demo( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Demo start. " + Instant.now( ) );

        DataSource dataSource = this.dataSource( );
        this.createEventTable( dataSource );
        this.persistCurrentMoment( dataSource );
        this.dumpEventTable( dataSource );

        System.out.println( "INFO - Demo end. " + Instant.now( ) );
    }

    private void createEventTable ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        @Language ( "SQL" )
        String sql = """
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_
                   (
                      id_ INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  -- ⬅ `identity` = auto-incrementing integer number.
                      when_ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
                    )
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement( )
        )
        {
            statement.execute( sql );
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    private void persistCurrentMoment ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        @Language ( "SQL" )
        String sql = """
                INSERT INTO event_ ( when_  )
                VALUES ( ? )
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.ofHours( 3 ) );
            System.out.println( "odt now is " + odt );
            preparedStatement.setObject( 1 , odt );
            int rowCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate( );
            if ( rowCount != 1 ) throw new IllegalStateException( "Failed to insert " + odt + " into database" );
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    public void dumpEventTable ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        @Language ( "SQL" )
        String sql = """
                SELECT *
                FROM event_
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection( ) ;
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement( ) ;
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            System.out.println( "---------|  Start dump of table event_  |--------------------" );
            while ( resultSet.next( ) )
            {
                int id = resultSet.getInt( "id_" );
                OffsetDateTime odt = resultSet.getObject( "when_" , OffsetDateTime.class );
                System.out.println( "id = " + id + " | odt = " + odt );
            }
            System.out.println( "---------|  End dump of table event_  |--------------------" );
        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    private javax.sql.DataSource dataSource ( )
    {
        org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource( );  // Implementation of `DataSource` bundled with H2.
        ds.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:SaveCurrentMomentDatabase;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" );
        ds.setUser( "scott" );
        ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
        ds.setDescription( "An example database for recording and retrieving the current moment." );
        return ds;
    }
}

When run:
…
odt now is 2024-08-27T00:36:16.317504+03:00
---------|  Start dump of table event_  |--------------------
id = 1 | odt = 2024-08-27T00:36:16.317504+03:00
---------|  End dump of table event_  |--------------------
…

Resolution
The java.time classes such as OffsetDateTime are capable of representing a moment with a fractional second resolving to nanoseconds (9 decimal places).
H2 limits date-time values to microseconds. If you pass a value with nanoseconds, H2 rounds to microseconds thereby eliminating the nanoseconds for a total of 6 decimal places.
In the code above, change the OffsetDateTime.now line to this:
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( 2024, 1, 23 , 15 , 0 ,0 ,123456789, ZoneOffset.ofHours( 3 ));

When run, we the nanoseconds 123456789 changed upon retrieval to 00.123457, going from 9 to 6 decimal places while rounding the sixth-place digit from a 6 to a 7.
…
odt now is 2024-01-23T15:00:00.123456789+03:00
---------|  Start dump of table event_  |--------------------
id = 1 | odt = 2024-01-23T15:00:00.123457+03:00
---------|  End dump of table event_  |--------------------
…


java.time.Instant is actually supported by some JDBC drivers, including driver of H2, but data type of a column should be TIMESTAMP(9) WITH TIME ZONE, because TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE rounds values to milliseconds. Unfortunately, Hibernate ORM chooses entirely wrong TIMESTAMP data type, therefore conversion from Instant to TIMESTAMP and back also depends on time zone.

@EvgenijRyazanov JDBC 4.2 & 4.3 do not map Instant. A JDBC driver implementer may choose to add support for Instant. But any code you write using that extra feature will not be portable to other drivers.

@EvgenijRyazanov My code example contradicts your claim that TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE rounds to milliseconds. You can see microseconds in my example output.

My mistake, I meant microseconds (6 digits), Instant support 9 digits and Instant.now() returns 7 digits on Windows and 9 digits on Linux in modern versions of Java, and various surprises are possible due to half-up rounding of values.

@EvgenijRyazanov Sure enough, you are correct about H2 rounding nanoseconds to microseconds. I added to the Answer some code demonstrating that fact. I am surprised by the rounding rather than truncation. Thank you.

@EvgenijRyazanov "… Instant.now returns 7 digits on Windows and 9 digits on Linux in modern versions of Java" — that's news to me. Common hardware clocks in conventional computers keep time only to microseconds as far as I knew. Perhaps you can post a Question and Answer asking about resolution of Instant.now, with exact code, results, and details, to prove that.

I found my mistake. I had to specify the timezone in the connection string.
url: jdbc:h2:file:./h2/mydb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=0;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;TIME ZONE=UTC

With "TIME ZONE=UTC" it works.
